# $group aggregation comparison in MongoDB vs SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a simple MongoDB collection of the following format:

```
Items:[
{
    TopicID    : 1,
    SubTopicID : 1,
    TopicDescription : "ABC"
},
{
    TopicID    : 1,
    SubTopicID : 2,
    TopicDescription : "BCD"    
},
{
    TopicID    : 2,
    SubTopicID : 1,
    TopicDescription : "CDE"    
}
..
..]
```

I have a list of 2 million items like so.

Doing a simple `$group` on the aggregation pipeline for this:

```
$group : {
           _id : "$TopicID",
           count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
```

takes approximately 5 seconds.(with `allowDiskUse : true`)

However, grouping this in a table of structure:

```
Items:
TopicID INT,
SubTopicID INT,
TopicDescription NVARCHAR(1000)
```

to get counts of SubTopics within a topic takes barely a second in SQL Server in a system of similar configuration. I have index created in TopicID for for MongoDB and SQL Server table.

The following is the explain:

```
{
    "stages" : [ 
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {},
                "fields" : {
                    "TopicID" : 1,
                    "_id" : 0
                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "mkl.Items",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {},
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : []
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$TopicID",
                "Count" : {
                    "$sum" : {
                        "$const" : 1.0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Only the `TopicID` is indexed for the `Items` collection

Is there anything I can do to increase mongodb performance for this use case?

Comment: could you post the `explain()` of the query ? And which fields of your item collection are indexed?

Comment: @felix This is done

Comment: One thing to notice, $group does not use indexed data. IDocumentation says : The $match and $sort pipeline operators can take advantage of an index when they occur at the beginning of the pipeline.

Comment: @MihirBhende Yes, I understand that, but, the $match, $limit etc are used to limit the data to a subset of the original set of data. What if I wanted to aggregate over the entire set rather than a subset?